# Is there a way to use function intersect on int[][] in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, intersection

Im having a array of arrays `int[][] = graph` and im trying to get the intersection of two sets like for examle `graph[i]` and `graph[j]`.

I tried something like this: `graph[i].Intersect(graph[j])` but im getting the message like

> int[] does not contain a definition for Intersect and no extension
>   method Intersect accepting a first argument of type int[] could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it impossible to use this function for array of arrays?

Comment: `using System.Linq;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intersect` is exactly the method you are looking for. Did you perhaps omit the using?
Here's an example.

```
//using System.Linq;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][] matrix = new[] { new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3 }, new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
    var intersection = matrix[0].Intersect(matrix[1]);
    foreach(var integer in intersection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(integer);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It outputs 2 and 3